# Altium: Via stitching not connecting to plane?

Tags: ground, altium, pcb-layers, via, ground-plane

I'm experiencing an issue in altium where my Via stitching vias on the GND net will not connect to my ground plane. Individually placed vias will connect fine through from the top layer polygon GND pour, the plane, and the bottom later polygon pour. As you can see below, the GND plane won't connect to the stitching vias (sides) in the same way it does to the single via (middle) despite being the same net.
[image]

I have looked at the stitching layer properties and it seems the plane is not present on the via layer editor when I look a the via style in 'full stack' mode.
[image]

[image]

I don't know why the plane layer wouldn't show up, yet all the signal layers of my 4-layer board will.

Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting that your ground layer is the only layer defined as a plane.

Comment: Vias connecting to planes can sometimes be buggy. It doesn't always show the connection until you run the DRC. I recommend trying that first and see what happens.

Comment: Have you tried to define your current plane as a signal layer and fill this layer with one big GND polygon?